# I want to use get-counter ”\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\memory\% committed bytes in use” to append to a csv in the next line

Tags: powershell, csv, append

How can i append the get-counter into the cell in my csv without overwriting the current data.

```
$path = "v:\logg\logg.csv"
$ram = Get-Counter "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\minne\% använda dedikerade byte"
$drivers = Get-Volume |Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter-ne $null}| select DriveLetter,Size,SizeRemaining,@{e={$_.Size - $_.SizeRemaining};l="Used"},@{e={[math]::Round(100 / ($_.size / $_.SizeRemaining) )};l="Total %"} 
$drivers | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"|Out-File $path -Append
```

I want it to look like this but with the get-counter added to the next empty cell:

[image]

If I try to add the $ram with add-content or out-file it will overwrite the whole file and remove the $drivers

If i try to do it like this:

```
$path = "v:\logg\hej.csv"
$ram = Get-Counter "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\minne\% använda dedikerade byte"
$ram |Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force

$drivers = Get-Volume |Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter-ne $null}| select DriveLetter,Size,SizeRemaining,@{e={$_.Size - $_.SizeRemaining};l="Used"},@{e={[math]::Round(100 / ($_.size / $_.SizeRemaining) )};l="Total %"} 
$drivers | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
```

[It will look like this, overwriting the whole part of $drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSQLK.png)

Comment: It is not clear to me where you want to add the text. Can you show an example of what you have and then what you want? The answer is either use a caculated property like you did at the end of line 3 or just `Out-File -Append` which you also have already done.

Comment: My Norwegian-Swedish-Danish-Icelandic-Finnish is a bit rusty I'm afraid.. Can you show us what `$ram` stores after the `Get-Counter "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\minne\% använda dedikerade byte"` please? And please do not put the desired output in a comment, but edit your question and paste it there in a formatted fashion so we can read.

Comment: Thanks for the image, but I still have no clue what the value of `$ram` is.. Is that an array or string or a number?

Comment: you can do that IF you either [1] build a new object with the old and new properties in it [2] use `Add-Member` to add a new property to the existing one. ///// however, when you do this `Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"|Out-File $path -Append` you break the CSV file format. it will no longer act as a proper CSV since that is not a column, but is instead a line on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

for just the committed bytes %, you can use this ...

```
$Counter = '\\{0}{1}' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, '\Memory\% Committed Bytes in Use'
$RAM_CommBytesInUse_Pct = [int](get-counter -Counter $Counter).
    CounterSamples[0].
    CookedValue
```

output on my system just now = `39`

however, ***you are not making a CSV file when you add all these things that don't have the same columns***. for instance, the date you inserted is a string in the `DriveLetter` column. to make a real CSV file, you will need to rearrange your properties in a new object.